# Pass variables and open another page with submit_tag in RoR

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Okay so I have one view named generateReport that takes a date from the user using 3 drop down boxes, one for month, one for day and one for year. I also have a submit_tag and when I click the button I want the date (all three parameters) sent to the createdReport view where the report will be displayed. This is how I have created the drop down boxes:

```
<select name="Date[month]">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
        .....
  <option>12</option>
</select>
<!Same for day>
<!Same for year>
<%= submit_tag "Submit", :day => "Date[day]", :month => "Date[month]", :year => "Date[year]" %>
```

and similarly for day and year. How can I go to the other page and have the day, month and year parameters available? The submit_tag above doesn't crash the page at least, but I still don't know how to get it to redirect me to another page and I'm still not sure that I even stored the parameters correctly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Any reason why you are using HTML and not <%= date_select :date %> ?.  You dont need to pass those variables through Submit, just use the params in your controller.

Comment: I'm having trouble using it. I can make the drop down boxes appear using <%=date_select("dateName", "dateMethod", :order => [:month, :day, :year])%> but I still don't know how I would pass the 3 variables from generateReport to createdReport.